How can I restore a Azure storage account with private endpoint connections?
I have a storage account with private endpoint connections. If I delete the storage account and keep the private endpoint, we would be left with a pe with connection to a non-existent resource.
If I want to restore the storage account and its connections- I created a storage account of the same name, can I restore the private endpoint connection out-of-the-box? Or do I need to recreate the private endpoints as well?
I tried with my testing account, it seems I would need to recreate the private endpoints?


How can I restore a Azure storage account with private endpoint connections?

If you have storage account with private endpoint and you deleted storage account , the private endpoint still exists with disconnected status, as below.

There is no way to restore existing Private endpoint connection and even we cannot link existing private endpoint to newly created storage account.

If you delete the storage account, you may need to create with private endpoint again and delete existing private endpoint.
Refer:  Recover a deleted storage account from another storage account
